# Drupal Node view modes

Tags: 7, nodes

I have setup multiple new view modes for a specific node. Full,Teaser,New Teaser,Custom Display.

Is there a way to view the same node with different URLS for the different view modes. Please let me know if i need to explain further.

Hopefully this makes some kind of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would be okay with having a parameter in the url control your view mode then you can add this code to your custom module using hook_entity_view_mode_alter().

For example:

http://www.yoursite.com?view_mode=Full

http://www.yoursite.com?view_mode=Teaser

.....

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_mode_alter().
 */
function my_module_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  // If there is a view_mode parameter in the url change the view mode to it.
  if (isset($_GET['view_mode'])) {
    $view_mode = $_GET['view_mode'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [View Mode Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page)

> Create separate pages for different view modes for a given content
>   type.
>
> On the manage display page for a given content type, you can assign
>   patterns for view modes so that they will become a page at the given
>   path. For instance, if you want to show the teaser at a specific URL,
>   you could do node/%/teaser. If you also use Display Suite or other
>   modules that allow you to create new view modes, you can use these
>   modes to display one or more fields from a node at a separate URL.

Or you can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) also.

Or a custom module could do this as well but no sense in reinventing the wheel :)